# How to disable Flutter/Dart experiment?

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently run the following command to enable the non-nullable experiment in my project.

```dart
dart --enable-experiment=non-nullable main.dart
```

The NNBD is enabled. But how can I disable it, there' no such command like

```dart
dart --disable-experiment=non-nullable main.dart
```

Had I enabled it in the `analysis_options.yaml` file, I would have disabled it easily. But how do I disable it now (without having to use the `analysis_options` option)

Comment: I think there is no solution for this yet even I was searching for this and found a open bug in the flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart 2.12 has turned on null safety by default. This is why you are getting errors in your editor. Add `// @dart=2.9` to the beginning of any files that you want to opt out of this feature.

Comment: That will run the app.

Comment: The command you ran does not toggle the feature. With the flag, the command runs the app with the experimental feature. Without the flag, it runs it without it.

Comment: I don't want to run and not run the app with or without the experiment. I want the compiler not to complain when I do `String s = null` i.e. I want to disable the experiment in my entire project. Sorry your post doesn't answer the post.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the command in your question. That command did not cause your problem. You also seem to be confusing an IDE with a compiler. However, I have updated my answer to resolve your actual problem.

Comment: What if I want to use feature from Dart `v2.12`, I won't be able to do so using your solution. I think you are getting confused. Having Dart v `>2.10` doesn't necessarily mean it will enable the experiment for you, you'll have to do it on your own.

Comment: Also this question wasn't specifically about the NNBD part. In general I wanted to know how can you disable a Flutter/Dart experiment which you enabled using the command line.

Comment: The experimental flags do not toggle experimental features in your editor. You are experiencing the errors because null safety is on by default in Dart 2.12+. I have updated my answer to a solution that will work for you. For sure this time ;)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however it seems like a workaround (+1 for sure). I should have mentioned that I'm only concerned about the IDE. Is there any other way besides this workaround to disable the experiment in my IDE?

Comment: There is not. This is being integrated as an actual feature of the language itself, therefore the going forward, programmers are expected to use it. As you can see, this is a breaking change, which is why they included the ability to opt files out. Simply to prevent applications from breaking while they are migrated to null safety.

Comment: I agree with you on this, but if something is marked "experiment" and there's a flag to "enable" it (to play with it), there must be a way to "disable" it. Not sure why team didn't do such thing. I think I should create an issue for this if I don't receive a satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is *experimental* only before 2.12. To be clear, 2.12 is in beta. 2.10 is the current stable release. When you run dart on the command line, it is almost assuredly running 2.10. You can verify this by running `dart --version`. This is why it is an *experimental* feature on your command line. If you are using the dev or beta sdk channel and building with a minimum constraint of 2.12.0-0, then you are using a version of the language where it is not an `experimental` feature. It is just a standard feature of the language.

Comment: Correct! But my question wasn't specific to NNBD. In general, how can I disable an experimental flag after enabling it via command line. In future, there'll be more experiments, right? In case I enable some to play around, how to revert it back.

Comment: You passing an experimental flag from the command line does NOT enable it in your editor. Only setting the experimental flags in analysis or launch options in the editor will. Your problem has nothing to do with the command you entered on the command line. It was caused by the SDK version constraints.

Comment: Sir, it actually enabled the experiment in my editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225009/discussion-between-lee3-and-idecode).

Comment: Hi, sorry for coming late as I never received the notification of your chat from the chat box. So, if I understood it right, you can enable/disable experiment if you have added them in the `analysis_options/yaml` file but once an experiment is enabled using command line, there's no going back?

Comment: No problem. I had the same issue. That's not quite correct. The experimental flag should only affect that launch in the Dart VM. If you were to run it again from the command line without the experimental flag, it should run as normal. However, this has changed since you started this topic. With Dart 2.12's official release at the beginning of March, assuming your SDK is updated, then the Dart run command will use null-safety by default. This is now a part of the language; going forward, you cannot avoid it. The way around it is to use the per-library language versioning as given in my answer.

Comment: According to this page https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution, there are no features added between Dart 2.9 and Dart 2.12 apart from Sound Null Safety, so there should be no issue doing this while you need to. You may also want to look into Dart's migration tool https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migration-tool in order to help you migrate your project to sound null safety.